# Java homework. "The method surfaceArea() is undefined for the type String"

Tags: java, eclipse, methods, syntax, undefined

for a homework assignment we simply had to copy the instructors code and read the notes. I did so but am left with the errors:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
Syntax error on token "box2", delete this token
The method surfaceArea() is undefined for the type String
Syntax error on token "box3", delete this token
The method surfaceArea() is undefined for the type String
```

and I cant see any difference between the code on paper and mine.

```
 package csc120lab3;

 import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

 public class Lab3 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    final String TITLE_STRING = "Lab 3 by _________"; //edit this and put in your name.

    Box box1; // 3 variables local to main method
    Box box2;
    Box box3;

    String output = ""; // we will output this later with JOptionPane

    box1 = new Box(5, 10, 15); //this is a call to the constructor
    //now call upon some instance methods. note use of of box1 before the method
    //names. In essence, box1 is the actor performing the method.
    //Note: below the "\n" cases text that follows to start on a new line.
    output += "Box 1 says : " + box1.myDescription() + "\n";
    output += "Surface area of box 1 is: " + box1.surfaceArea() + "\n";

    box2 = new Box(4, 11, 13); //this is a call to the constructor
    output += "Box 2 says : " + box2.myDescription() + "\n";
    output += "Surface area of box 2 is: " box2.surfaceArea() + "\n";

    box3 = new Box(4, 14, 19); //this is a call to the constructor
    output += "Box 2 says : " + box3.myDescription() + "\n";
    output += "Surface area of box 3 is: " box3.surfaceArea() + "\n";

    //now we call upon an instance method that takes another box as an argument
    //in the first line, box1 is the actor and box2 is being passed to the method
    //as an argument

    output += "Box2 fits inside of box 1 : " + box1.willHold(box2) + "\n";
    output += "Box1 fits inside of box 2 : " + box2.willHold(box1) + "\n";
    output += "Box3 fits inside of box 1 : " + box1.willHold(box3) + "\n\n";

    //next line call upon the class method. Note use of box before method name
    output += "We now have a total of " + Box.howManyBoxes() + "boxes created.";

    //showMesageDiaglog() is a class method of the JOptionPane class. we call it here
    //INFORMATION_MESSAGE is a class constant that we pass as an argument to method call
    //showMessageDialog() is a void method, hence it does not return anyhing to us
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, output, TITLE_STRING, JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

}

}

class Box {
    //This class is actually a hybrid of the two flavors of classes that we discussed in 
    //class. it uses all 5 of the big things that we use into class definitions, namely: class
    //variables, class methods, instance variables, instance methods, and has a constructor method

    //class variable (not use of static)
    public static int boxCounter = 0;

    //class method. header uses static. class itself performs this method
    //this method has no need for any perameters to be passed into it, hence ()
    //it will return an int vaue to the caller, hence "int" as part of the header

    public static int howManyBoxes(){
        //return the value of the class variable.
        return boxCounter;
    }   

    // 3 instance variables [note no use of static]
    //each object of type Box will get its own copy of each of these
    //they are marked as private so that ONLY the methods of this class can access them
    private float width;
    private float length;
    private float height;

    //class costructor (note: no return type and method name is same as class name)
    public Box (float newWidth, float newLength, float newHeight){
        width = newWidth;
        height = newHeight;
        length = newLength;

        //and eachtime we do create a new Box we will also up the boxCounter by one
        boxCounter = boxCounter + 1;
    }

    //an instance method note the lack of static
    public float volume(){
        float answer; //this is a local variable
        answer = width * height * width;
        return answer;
        //note: could replace above three lines with just: return (width * height * length)
    } //end volume

    //another instance method
    public float surfaceArea(){
        //our box has sides and a bottom, but no top
        float bottomArea = length * width;
        float sidesArea = 2 * (length * height) + (width * height);
        return (bottomArea + sidesArea);
    } //end surfaceArea

    //another instance method (the object returns a string that describes its size)
    //note that += causes the right hand string to be appended to the end of the string 
    //on the left side
    public String myDescription(){
        String answer;
        answer = "I am a box with a width of " + width;
        answer += ", a length of " + length;
        answer += " and a height of " + height + ".  ";
        answer += "I also happen to have a volume of " + volume() + ".";
        return answer;
    }//end my description

    //another instance method. this method tells us if the box given in the parameter
    //list below. (i.e. otherBox) will fit fully inside of this box. return true if it does,
    //otherwise return false. note that the other box can be turned on its side or whatever 
    //to make it fit. 
    public boolean willHold(Box otherBox){


        float myMax = Math.max(Math.max(width, length), height);
        float otherBoxMax = Math.max(Math.max(otherBox.width, otherBox.length), otherBox.height);

        float myMin = Math.min(Math.min(width, length), height);
        float otherBoxMin = Math.min(Math.min(otherBox.width, otherBox.length), otherBox.height);

        float myMid = width + length + height - myMin - myMax;
        float otherBoxMid = otherBox.width + otherBox.length + otherBox.height - otherBoxMin -
                            otherBoxMax;

        //below && means and
        if (otherBoxMax < myMax && otherBoxMin < myMin && otherBoxMid < myMid){
            return true; //other box fits in me!
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    }//end willHold
```

}//end class Box

Comment: You're missing the `+` between the end of your `"Surface area..."` string and the start of your method call for `surfaceArea()` on your two `Box` objects. You got it right for `box1`, but not the other two.

Comment: I've flagged to close this question due to the simple typographical error.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot 2 plus signs:

```
output += "Surface area of box 2 is: " box2.surfaceArea() + "\n";
```

should be

```
output += "Surface area of box 2 is: " + box2.surfaceArea() + "\n";
```

Comment: haha thank you so much. its always the small stuff you overlook. the error makes sense now about it not being a string

Answer (score 0):

You're missing concatation operator "+" in this line some other lines

```
output += "Surface area of box 2 is: " box2.surfaceArea() + "\n";
```